# What $h$ and $k$ would make this system have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: matrices

If there are an infinite number of solutions to the system

$$\left|\begin{array}{cc|c} -5 & 6 & h\\ -8 & k & -7\end{array}\right|$$

then what do $h$ and $k$ equal?

---

I know that for a system to have infinity many solutions then both of the rows must be equal.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  I thought I wrote my system in the question.

Comment: @ground.clouds1 The way you have written down is unclear. If you meant $$\begin{bmatrix} -5 & 6\\ -8 & k\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} h \\ -7\end{bmatrix}$$ then it is preferable to separate the second column and third column with a vertical straight line. Currently, it looks like just a $2 \times 3$ matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the system you have is
$$\begin{bmatrix} -5 & 6\\ -8 & k\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} h \\ -7\end{bmatrix}$$
For this to have infinite solutions, the two rows must be linearly dependent i.e. the second row must be a scalar multiple of the first row.

Note that $- 8 = - 5 \times \dfrac85$. Hence, $k = 6 \times \dfrac85 = \dfrac{48}5$ and $-7 = \dfrac85 \times h \implies h = - \dfrac{35}8$.

Answer (score 2):

the rows of matrix are proportional
$$(-5):(-8)=6:k=h:(-7)$$
$$-5k=-48,h=35/-8$$
$$k=\frac{48}{5},h=-\frac{35}{8}$$

Comment: What do you think, Adi,about my approach? +

Answer (score 2):

If you have the system of two lines: $$\begin{cases}
  ax+by=c \\
  a'x+b'y=c'
\end{cases}$$ then the system is infinite solutions iff we have: $$\frac{a}{a'}=\frac{b}{b'}=\frac{c}{c'}$$ Of course we have some restrictions on the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the rows must be equal. They should give you the same information, which occurs only if one is a scalar multiple of the other. Therefore

$\frac{-5}{-8}=\frac{6}{k}=\frac{h}{-7}$. This gives you $k=\frac{48}{5}$ and $h=\frac{-35}{8}$.